# How to escape slash ('/') in username in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, escaping

Trying to create a user that has a '/' character in its username results in invalid username error because it contains invalid characters.

Is there a way to escape a slash ('/') when creating a user in wordpress so that the '/' also gets saved as part of the username? Thanks

Edit (may help to diagnose): There are thousands of users already registered that have slashes in their usernames. However, as of 4th of December we are not able to register any new users in that same format (username format: int/int). I did not modify any parts of code.

Comment: Did you try `\/`? backslash slash

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, same error occurs

Comment: Is it a coding error or application error? Are usernames allowed to have slashes in them?

Comment: @user3783243 I have added an edit above which might answer your questions

Comment: I don't have time to write any code, but the function that actually creates a user is [`wp_insert_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/) which calls [`sanitize_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_user/) which is what is stripping the slash. In that function, there's a filter called `sanitize_user` that will give you the username from before and after, and that's where it is probably best to handle this. However, don't be surprised if other things break. WordPress is escaping for a reason.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I saw that methods mentioned above call [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) which should just replace invalid characters. Meaning that error I am getting gets thrown in some other place in the code, is that correct?

Comment: If an exception is thrown, it should have a stacktrace that you can pinpoint to a specific file and line number, so I'd start there. You can post that here, too, if you need help diagnosing things. But as I said, WordPress is doing this for a reason, so don't be surprised if you continue to find edge cases in the future.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks, not sure if I could catch it. I am trying to play around with sanitize_user method and I found code which prohibits some of the characters, but can't find exact point where slash is prohibited.

Comment: @Vedo If `$strict` is true the `/` wont be allowed. `if ( $strict ) {
        $username = preg_replace( '|[^a-z0-9 _.\-@]|i', '', $username );
    }` The question is too minimal as is. Also that regex WP used can be simpler, and comment contradicts what it does.

Comment: @user3783243 We're on the same page. Just added a '/' to the preg_replace you mentioned above. Problem is that user.php has validate_username method and $sanitized variable still has removed slash for some reason. I have debugged and seems like the call to apply_filters method at the end of sanitize_uzer in formatting.php somehow still removes the slash

Comment: Cant' just change call so second parameter is false?

Comment: Yep, tried that also. Slash gets removed from username completely